# All I get is a blank page when I visit localhost:9080

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

I have been using udacity.com to learn to program but I ran into some problem with my code(python). The application is post to allow to put down the day you were born and when you push submit it's post to say "Thanks That's a totally valid day!". It's not doing it. The application just restarts again. Can some tell me why the is statement is not working and how to fix it.

```
import webapp2
form="""

    <form>
        What is your birthday?
        <br>
        <label>Month<input type="type" name="month"></label>
        <label>Day<input type="type" name="day"></label>
        <label>Year<input type="type" name="year"></label>
        <div style="color: red">%(error)s</div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

"""
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write_form(self, error=""):
        self.response.out.write(form % {"error": error} )
    def get(self):
        self.write_form()

        def post(self):
            user_month = valid_month(self.request.get('month'))
            user_day = valid_day(self.request.get('day'))
            user_year = valid_year(self.request.get('year'))

            if not (user_month and user_month and user_year):
                self.write_form("That doesn't look valid to me, friend.")
            else:
                self.response.out.write("Thanks! That's a totally valid day!")


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/',MainPage)], debug=True)
```

Comment: your configuration is most likely incorrect, but that is just speculation as anyone else's attempt at an answer will be as well. there is not a specific question articulated here to actually answer, it basically says *my thing is not working*. your problem is not something that anyone else can solve but you with this lack of information. *links to external resources, especially images on 3rd part hosting is highly discouraged as it leads to dead links and useless questions and answers.*

Comment: My question is why is a piece of code that's post to work coming out blank when put it in Google app engine locahost. I am ask for you guys to please look over it to see if there is any error or miss types.

Comment: Usually the App Engine port is 8080 and not 9080.

Comment: I change the localhost to 8080 and it still is blank

Comment: Do you guys have experience with using python on Google app engine

Comment: Is the dev_appserver running?

Comment: The dev_appserver is running

Answer (score 2):

That fragment has a syntax error. If you're watching the terminal/console, you'll notice Python complain about the `else` (which is missing a trailing `:`). Watching the console, and understanding what it's saying, is key if you want to make progress.

With that fixed, you'll see the form. Then, when you trying posting, you'll get a "405 Method not allowed" because the `post` method is over-indented.

Comment: How do I not over-indented the post?

Comment: Python is very sensitive to indentation. In the fragment you posted, the `post` method is a private method of `get`. If you remove indentation starting at `def post` so that it's at the same level as `def get`, then the `post` method will be visible to routing. That will resolve the 405 error.

Comment: Does the code look ok now. Here is the link to the code:https://plus.google.com/u/1/115545843446144625696/posts/bobdBaWQ6hx?pid=6171953551530743762&oid=115545843446144625696

Comment: It's missing `def post` from in front the `(self)`. Otherwise, find. You can also edit your original post.

Comment: It works but when I push submit it does not go to ""Thanks! That's a totally valid day!"". Where in the code did i miss up?

Comment: Perhaps you meant `self.request.get('get')` to get 'day' instead of 'get'.

Comment: user_day = valid_day(self.request.get('get')    to        user_day = valid_day(self.request.get('day')

Comment: i changed it and i still it the same thing

Comment: Update the post and add the `valid_*` methods.

Comment: Do you mean def valid_post or just valid_post

Comment: valid_post or just valid_post did not work. where do i place the valid_* at. Thank you

Comment: Let's approach this another way. At least one of `user_day`, `user_month`, or `user_year` is False. Given what you've learned so far, what's the simplest thing you could do to tell which is False? Then work backwards to why.

Answer (score 0):

Add method="post" to your form tag just above the text "What is your birthday?". You are using post method to post data to the form but the button submit doesn't know that you are using post as the tag  does not have method="post" in it.

Also check my answer on one of your other related post here. [python post and get commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596595/python-post-and-get-commands)