# Google App Engine Python 2.7 Launcher - Localhost shows a blank page

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I was trying to complete an online tutorial and got stuck on this part. The app is running and the port is entered correctly. Instead of the form, the browser displays a blank page.

```
import webapp2

form="""
<form method="post">
What is your birthday?
<br>
<br>

<label> Month
    <input type="text" name="month">
</label>

<label> Day
    <input type="text" name="day">
</label>

<label> Year
    <input type="text" name="year">
</label>

<br>
<br>

<input type="submit">
</form>
"""

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write(form)

    def post(self):
        user_month = valid_month(self.request.get('month'))
        user_day = valid_day(self.request.get('day'))
        user_year = valid_year(self.request.get('year'))

    if not (user_month and user_day and user_year):
        self.response.out.write(form)
    else:
        self.response.out.write("Thanks! That's a totally valid day!")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage)
], debug=True)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [All I get is a blank page when I visit localhost:9080](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415548/all-i-get-is-a-blank-page-when-i-visit-localhost9080)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the log generated by the GoogleAppEngineLauncher?

It looks like there are a few mistakes in your code:

- The indentation in your `post()` method is incorrect.  The if-else statement needs to be further indented.
- I don't see a definition of the function `valid_month`

Your log should show you these and perhaps other errors and give you the info you need to fix them.